# integer value from object in another activity is not being received properly from another class. Not Answered Yet

Tags: java, android, arrays

In my java android application im working on I have ran into a problem. In my activity I have an object that has a int value called addSpend. I have another java class that has a string array. I retrieved the object's value addSpend from the activity into this class and I wanted to put it in the String array but when i ran the app the string just returned the integer as 0 why is that?

Here is my code from the activity:

```
  Ship testin = new Ship();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hangar);

    testin.setAddSpend(5);
```

Here is my code from the other class

```
    HangarActivity hAObject= new HangarActivity();
   int test = hAObject.testin.getAddSpend();

    String[] shipDesc = {"10 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 100$",
            "50 Planets Every 5 Secs \n" + test,
            "100 Planets Every 5 Secs \n 1500$",
            "500 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 3000$",
            "1000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 7500$",
            "5000 Planets Every 4 Secs \n 15000$",
            "10000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 50000$",
            "30000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n 100000$",
            "60000 Planets Every 3 Secs \n  500000$",
            "100000 Planets Every 1 Secs \n 1000000$"};



TextView2.setText(shipDesc[1]);
```

When you answer can you also explain how to fix the problem as well as tell 
me what the problem is thanks.

Edit:
The answers I have recieved are about Intents and getting data from activities. I have one activity and the other a normal class so get Intents wont work. Can someone help me answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to instantiate activities with *new*. This way the Activity is not managed by Android and so the Lifecycle-Methods (*onCreate*) are not invoked.

Launch activities with *Intent* like this: [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: Im not starting the activity I want to get a value from it

Comment: You are instantiating the activity with *new HangarActivity();* - dont be surprised that *onCreate* is not invoked...?!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to value between actives ,you have to use bundle, check example for this
http://congeritc.blogspot.com.tr/2012/04/android-passing-values-between-views.html